# React Native generating and Sharing a deep link on social media

Tags: react-native, deep-linking

I am developing a mobile app, in which i have to share a post on social media, we dont have the website for this app, only mobile app, i read some articles, in which they use the Linking api , but i don't understand

1. how am i suppose to generate a link like myapp://post/123
2. after generating, how can i share it on social media, if i use the Share API, it is only shared as a text, and not a clickable hypertext.

   3. after sharing a clickable link, how can i program it to open my mobile app, and check if the user does not have the app installed ,then redirect them to playstore, and if they have the app installed , then open the mobile app, and navigate to the screen i want it to.

can someone please guide me the flow of doing this, or if you have an article explaining this, or maybe some example on github.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Branch.io](https://branch.io/), This product will help you to create and manage the deep link URL.